# comparing two different gridview's selected value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Hello I have threegrid views with the select row enabled. The user will select an item from each grid view then on selected index change the values will be compared to the other two gridviews to see if they are equal. While debugging I can see that they are the same so I'm not sure why the if statement is always passing as true. Is it possibly comparing the indexes? Thanks for the help!

```
If gvCustomer.SelectedValue IsNot gvSiteAddress.SelectedValue Then
            dataSourceGVCust.SelectCommand = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SelectCustomer") & " WHERE CUST_NO LIKE '%" & gvSiteAddress.SelectedValue.ToString & "%' ORDER BY CUST_NAME"
        End If
If gvJobNumber.SelectedValue IsNot gvSiteAddress.SelectedValue Then
     dataSourceGVJobNumber.SelectCommand = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SelectJobNumber") & " WHERE CUST_NO LIKE '%" & gvSiteAddress.SelectedValue.ToString & "%' ORDER BY JOB_NO"
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing the `IsNot` operator.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx

`IsNot` does a reference equals.  That is, are the two objects **PHYSICALLY** pointing to the same instance of an object -- not just do they have the same value.

Change `IsNot` to `<>` and you should be back in action.

EDIT: A cast to the proper type is likely required.  For example, if your values are a numeric ID then something like:

```
If CType(gvJobNumber.SelectedValue, Integer) <> CType(gvSiteAddress.SelectedValue, Integer) Then
```

Or if `String` then substitute `String` where you see `Integer` above.

Comment: when I change the operator to <> I get "Option strict on disallows operands of type object for operator '<>'. Use the 'Is' operator to test for object identity." That is why I went with isnot, I could turn it off but isn't it best practice to turn it on?

Comment: I see.  `SelectedValue` is an object not a string or integer and that's so you have flexibility on setting the value.  What base type *is* your `SelectedValue`?  What is it referencing? Numeric ID?  See the edit to my answer above.